# Purpose of capacitor connected across AC input in a smart bulb?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, ac

I recently had an IKEA smart bulb (TRÅDFRI, E27) go bang, but it continued working. After disassembling it, I discovered that only a single capacitor had failed. The capacitor is connected directly across the AC input (before the rectifier) and has the marking `N154K 400VSD`.

I can’t find such a feature on any other lamps. What is this capacitor for, if is it required, and what would be a suitable value to replace it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without further analysis, the LED lamp has a switching power supply, and switching power supplies have mains filter caps to make the lamps fit to current electromagnetic interference standards. Cheap/old/unofficial lamps may not have filter caps.

It may not be worth to repair it, but if you do, please understand that you can't simply put any random capacitor there, or it might just go bang immediately or become a fire hazard.

As that capacitor is directly between mains live and neutral, it needs to have a special safety class rating for that use. Unless you can find such a cap from reputable sources, don't fix it with capacitor bought from suspicious sources.

154 means 150nF, 400V, K is likely tolerance of 10%.

Comment: The special safety class required for capacitors between live and neutral is "class X". I hope the failed cap had an "X1" or "X2" marking. If you were to replace the lamp, make sure the replacement cap is certified to conform to class X.

Answer (score 10):

This is most likely used for noise suppression.  That is: it reduces the amount of noise that is generated by the lamp from getting back into the AC Mains.

This is only a guess on my part, but I suspect that it was added to the design because the lamp did not meet EMI limits established by the certifying authority.

Comment: The "154" refers to the value which is 150 nF ( 0.150 uF), the "K" is probably tolerance which is 10%. This is a special capacitor for usage across mains (probably has VDE, UL, and a bunch of other markings).

Comment: @qrk this is *hopefully* a special capacitor... I've seen too many standard 400v ceramics in SMPSUs.  And they're even worse, because they bridge the transformer, so if they fail short the -ve is now live.